# php logic on a system shopping cart and session value management

Tags: php, session, logic, shopping-cart

this is a question about the logic of an e-commerce cart built in php:

i have an item in the cart saved with a session in php, this session is named by a composed string where the unique key is given by the product_id:

```
$this->session->data['quote_total_'.$product_id];
```

the problem is when i add the same product in the cart but with diefferent price - the price is generated automatically by the system at the change of misures, options, and quantity - 
indeed the first value of the cart session that is the value of the first product price is overwritten by the new one.  which is the best method to avoid this overwrite for you?

i was thinking about a unique value to append at the name of the session but i don't understand which ones...

Answer (score 0):

How about making this variable an array instead of a primitive datatype?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the product ID as a key, just let the key be created automatically which will be numerical and incremented with each product

```
// add a product - new product will always be added
$this->session->data[] = array(
    'product_id' => 123,
    'qty' => 1,
    'name' => 'Product Name',
    'price' => 10
);


// you can iterate over the products like
foreach($this->session->data as $product)
{
    print_r($product);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Append price with product id in session variable to uniquely identify each product with different prices.And also use array to store multiple products.

Comment: i had tryed before but i can't recover the price from the previous POST

Comment: at the time of adding product,do you have price?

Comment: for add price like an id into session' name i got to change a float number in a integer simply replacing the comma with nothing, then,  for retrieve the price in the cart method getProducts() i need to know the price so i can't work, i thought... am i right?

Comment: Rather you can use product id and price as strings and concate them to uniquely identify each product with different prices.e.g. product id=123 and prices are 45.2 then $this->session->data['123'.'45.2'];

Comment: i can't understand it won't to work, this is the page that you can do what i'm trying to explay, fill the form and click the blu button "acquista" then you can see that the cart is updated, try again to click the blu button once again after changing the width and height input field ["Base (cm)"; Altezza (cm)], look into the cart then you can see what happen: there are two products with different options but with the same price, the last...

Comment: this is the link: http://www.nowprint.it/Stampa_Grande_Formato/Manifesti_per_Affissione/Manifesti_Affissione

Comment: I checked the above link.And got what problem you are facing.

Comment: you can use product id and price as strings and concate them to uniquely identify each product with different prices.e.g. product id=123 and prices are 35.1,45.2 then $this->session->data['123-35.2']; and $this->session->data['123-45.2']; will identify each product separately.

Answer (score -2):

Create multidimensional array such as

```
$data = array([0]=>array(
    'product_id' => 123,
    'qty' => 1,
    'name' => 'Product Name',
    'price' => 10),
    [1]=>array(
    'product_id' => 123,
    'qty' => 2,
    'name' => 'Product Name',
    'price' => 20)
);
```

Comment: It is not a good idea. the quantity must be 3 and price should be 30 if it's the same product.